# webkit-filter changing z-index stacking order

Tags: css

Why does applying a webkit filter changes the layers order?

See this minimal example:

```js
setInterval(function(){

 t.classList.toggle('grayed');
    
}, 1000)
```

```css
.floater {
    position: fixed;
    top: 5vh;
    left: 5vw;
    width: 90vw;
    height: 90vh;
    z-index: 99;
    background: yellow;
    display: none;
}
td:hover .floater{
    display: initial;
}

.grayed td{
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0.5);
}

td{
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<table id="t">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5<br>
            (Mouse over this)
            <div class="floater">HELLO</div>
        </td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Anything other than `none` in the `filter` property creates a new stacking order. #6 though #9 come after `div class="floater"` in your html so I guess that's why they show on top of it while #1 through #5 are behind the floater.

Comment: @Ihazkode  
is there any way to force floater to display above everything even when the .grayed class is applied? z-index seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

The order changes because when the effect is rendered it gets moved to a different stacking contexts (or "layer"). The solution I found was to place whatever should show in front after the element with this effect.

Hover over the buttons on the left and right corners.
http://aminhafamilia.com.br/layout-options/4.html
http://aminhafamilia.com.br/layout-options/4a.html

Page 4.html displays correctly and page 4a.html does not. the only difference is that the text that I want to show on top is actually after the header (which has the filter). Note that no z-index can fix it because they are not in the same stacking context. Moving it down changes the stacking context.

Answer (score 0):

- Child's `z-index` is set to the same stacking index as its parent, hence why it's not working.
- If you are willing to take the floater out of it's table parent, you could try the below JS approach with `mouseover` & `mouseout` (to close).

```js
setInterval(function() {
  t.classList.toggle('grayed');
  document.querySelector('.floater').classList.toggle('grayed');
}, 1000)

document.querySelector('.toHover').addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  document.querySelector('.floater').classList.add('open');
})
document.querySelector('.floater').addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  document.querySelector('.floater').classList.remove('open');
})
```

```css
.floater {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5vh;
  left: 5vw;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
  z-index: 1;
  background: yellow;
  display: none;
}

.grayed td {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0.5);
}

.grayed {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0.5);
}

.open {
  display: initial;
}

td {
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<table id="t">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td class="toHover">5<br> (Mouse over this)
      <div>HELLO</div>
    </td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="floater">HELLO</div>
```